# Hide entire row and unhide when done

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to hide rows in column A that contain "0" but unhide the columns if a value entered is > 0

I tried this code. When the value is > 0 and the hidden rows appear there is a date in the B column and it errors the rest of my info on the sheet. I tried commenting out the `OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber` along with other lines that use this and I'm just getting errors.

The other info in the following cells are using a VLOOKUP which pulls data from another tab (part number, description of part, and price).

```
Sub HideTodaysZeroValues()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber As Integer ' makes it easier to edit the column number
    OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber = 1
    For Each c In Range("A25:A52")
        If c.Value = "0" Then ' If Col A is zero
            'Check if stored date column is populated
            If Len(c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value) > 0 Then
                'if it is populated, compare date with now, and if its equal to 1, show it
                If DateDiff("d", c.Offset(0, 1).Value, Now()) > 0 Then
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
                Else
                    'else hide it and store the date it was hidden
                    'As its stands right now this code will only unhide the rows from yesterday, any older rows will be rehiddne
                    'If this is not desired, change the "= 1" above, to be " > 0"
                    c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value = Now()
                    c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
                End If
            Else
                'comes here if stored date is not populated, which will happen first time a row needs to be hidden
                c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber).Value = Now()
                c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
            End If
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

When the rows reappear I would like for the data from the VLOOKUP to be inserted instead of the date and time the cell was hidden using the code above.

Comment: What do you mean with *I'm just getting errors* ? What errors - runtime errors? Formula errors? Which statement causes the error?

Comment: *it errors the rest of my info on the sheet.* It seems likely that other cell(s) are referencing the value in `c.Offset(0, OffsetStoredDateColumnNumber)` via formula (e.g., Vlookup, maybe)?  Since you're dumping `Now()` into that cell, it's that timestamp value that is the likely culprit. So, the solution is to revise ALL formulae that depend on the values in column B, I think.

Comment: Alternatively, rather than overwriting whatever is in column B, maybe just add a *comment* to the cell in Column A. Or use a `Name` to store the timestamp, etc.

Comment: Do you have dates in column B?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you got this code off the internet, and it does hide the row if `0` is in the first column, with other criteria.

What it also does is check column B for a date, and if the difference in the date and Today is `>0`, it will unhide the row, or if the date is `Today` it will hide the row. If there is `no date` in column B, it will *add Today's date*.

I will also assume you don't have any dates in column B, and when the code inserts a date it screws up any formulas you have.

That said, I will show you two ways to hide and unhide rows. one with no dates in column B, and one with dates in column B, just in case you have dates.

First, Go to the Developers Tab and click "Visual Basic", add the below Subs to `ThisWorkbook` code window.

```
Sub HideIf0()
'This sub will hide rows if the first cell is 0
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A25:A52")

        If c.Value = "0" Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub HideIf0andToday()
    'This sub will hide rows if the first cell is 0 and the cell to the right is todays date

    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A25:A52")

        If c.Value = "0" And c.Offset(, 1).Value = Date Then
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            c.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If

    Next
End Sub


Sub UnhideRng()
'This sub will allow you to unhide all the rows when you are done
    Range("A25:A52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

[image]
Test Data

[image]
Hide If 0

[image]
Hide If 0 and Today

You will need to add 2 buttons to your worksheet. Name one "Hide" and the other "Unhide" Why? because running code to hide rows and then unhide the rows immediately in the same code is useless.

- Add buttons: Go to the Developers Tab and click "Insert" in "Controls", Click "Button" under "Form Controls". Draw two buttons on your worksheet. Rename one "Hide" and the other "Unhide"

Right Click the "Hide" button and click "Assign Macro"; If you don't have dates in column B, then select "ThisWorkBook.HideIf0" macro. If you do have dates in column B then select "ThisWorkbook.HideIf0andToday"

Right Click the "Unhide" button and click "Assign macro", select "ThisWorkbook.UnhideRng"

Go to your work sheet, select and cell to unclick the button, and then click the Hide button, when you are done reviewing the data, you can click the Unhide button.